# How do I print the sum of a 2 numbers counting down from the sum to 1

Tags: c++

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int num;
  int num2;
  int sum;
  int i = 0;


  cout << "enter a number: ";
  cin >> num;
  cout << "enter another number: ";
  cin >> num2;

 sum = num + num2;

 for(i = 0 ; i <= sum ; i++)
  {
      cout << "loop iteration: " << sum << endl;
  }
  return 0;

}
```

this is the code i have so far. Right now it works fine it computes the sum, however, say the sum is 3, it'll print:

```
loop iteration: 3
loop iteration: 3
loop iteration: 3
```

but I am trying to get it to print:

```
loop iteration: 3
loop iteration: 2
loop iteration: 1
```

I'm not sure if the issue lies inside my for statement, I think I may have the order wrong.

Comment: Look into `sum--` and a `while` loop.

Comment: Your `for` loop needs to count down, not up. Think about how you'd do it on paper (or in your *I'd like it to print* block). You'd start with the `sum`, and subtract one each time, right? Why isn't your `for` loop doing the same? And why are you outputting `sum` when it's not changing during the looping? It clearly will always produce the same output if it's not being changed. What value *is* changing on each pass through the loop?

Comment: a potential first step is to change `sum` to `i` in your cout: `cout << "loop iteration: " << i << endl;` which will print a sequence, instead of the same number every time. It's not the right sequence, but it's a start.

Comment: i think i got confused while trying to make sure that loop iteration lines were printed the right amount of times

Comment: Please don't clutter your title with useless repetition of the tag or commentary about your experience level. It's clear from your question that you're a beginner; an absolute expert wouldn't need to ask this question. :-)

Comment: I was just trying to be thorough and make sure enough info was available to receive proper guidance. I appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: C++ is clear from the `c++` tag at the bottom; the tagging system works extremely well here and doesn't need help. And as I said, the content of the question tells us you're a beginner; it's not needed to point it out at all, much less broadcast it in the title of the question. :-)

Comment: Okay I got it. All I asked was for a little assistance, not a lesson on how to use the website :-)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are printing the same `sum` over and over and not decrementing the `sum`. either you can decrement the `sum` within `for` loop using `sum--` operator or you can modify the loop as shown below.

```
for(i = sum ; i >= 1 ; i--)
{
    cout << "loop iteration: " << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why did you do it for them instead of just offering suggestions? You've defeated the entire purpose of the assignment. I could have written the answer instead of offering hints in the comment I left, but it's better if the poster does their own work and learns. They may appreciate the copy/paste solution, but their teacher (and the people the poster will work with in the future) don't.

Comment: @Ken White: I recently started answering on stackoverflow and I get really excited to answer as quickly as possible :-) . But I agree with your point and will keep that in mind. :-)

Comment: Playing FGITW isn't always a smart idea. But you'll learn that pretty quickly on your own. And trying to increase your own rep while not benefiting the poster or the site itself backfires really badly. I'd be cautious. :-)

Comment: @Ken White: Sir, I welcome your comments and will incorporate them while I post in future. Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int num;
int num2;
int sum;
int i = 0;


cout << "enter a number: ";
cin >> num;
cout << "enter another number: ";
cin >> num2;

sum = num + num2;

while(sum != 0){

  cout << "loop iteration: " << sum << endl;
  sum--;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, this doesn't answer the question asked, which is about a `for` loop. Second, it offers no explanation about why this would be a solution or how it improves the code. Code dump answers aren't really useful, and should be avoided. The goal of this site is to share knowledge, and knowledge means instruction.